# Unable to transfer ownership Facebook page - Admin dispute request fails - You have no eligible admined Pages

Tags: facebook

I'm currently trying to transfer the ownership of a Facebook page to myself. The account that created the page originally doesn't exist anymore or is untraceable. I do have the right administrator permissions on the respective page but it's not possible to transfer ownership to my account.

Steps to reproduce:

- Go to the page
- Go to settings
- Go to page roles
- Go to "If you have trouble contacting the Page owner, start a dispute request to claim access to your Page in Business Manager."
- Click on Admin dispute request
- Then the process becomes stuck with this message:

I am having an issue with accessing my Page
This form is for people who've lost their Page admin status because one of the Pages admins was hacked. If you're having trouble accessing your Page for any other reason, please return to the Help Center.
Which Page have you lost access to?
You have no eligible admined Pages.

see:
[screenshot error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIgfl.png)

I can't find any other options to transfer the owner rights. Can anyone help me with this problem? It's driving me mad for over a year ;-)

Regards,

Robert